# Sonoma, Xcode 15: missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun, 5 reinstalls of xcode CLT

Tags: homebrew, xcrun

HELP I upgraded to MacOS 14 (Sonoma, Xcode 15.0) and git fails.  Homebrew as well as my work depends on git.

xcrun: error: invalid active developer path  (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at:  /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun

In case it helps, I have already reinstalled xcode command tools 5 times already. Problem happens on 2 different mac machines (a M1 Studio and a macbook pro 14"). I've also installed Xcode by hand.  Neither

/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun

nor

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcrun

exists.

Answer (score 0):

I tried a sixth time reinstalling xcode Command Line Tools, about 36 hours after I first tried.  I think the XCode CLT changed in the meantime.  It smoothly went back to working again.

thanks to all who tried to help.

Comment: You can leave a comment on such an answer, not in the actual thread!